# Scale an image in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and Java and don't know how to scale an image in an image view. 
I want something like this: `MyImageView.setHeight(300)`
I don't want to distort the image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This solution might be overkill for your current question, but if you have to show images in your app, I recommend using an image handling library such as Picasso or Glide.

If you are to use Picasso, add it to your dependencies by adding the following line to your gradle files :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

Then in your Kotlin file, when you are about to load the picture onto an ImageView,
do it using Picasso using the following lines :

```
Picasso
            .get()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will use picasso now!

Comment: I recommend Picasso over Glide, if your app doesn't do too much with images, as Picasso is lighter in size and their usage is similar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with rgv. Use an image handling library, preferably Picasso. It can reduce a lot of hardwork and also, the result is better than what you would have got by scaling image manually.